# Как в .gitignore добавить правило?

Tags: git, github

Нужно в .gitignore добавить такое правило, чтобы git игнорировал файлы, у которых нет расширения.
К примеру example.exe - добавляем в git, а файл example - игнорируем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*
!*/
!*.*
```

`*` говорит git'у игнорировать всё.

`!*/` затем **не** игнорировать всё, что является каталогом. Это очень важно.

`!*.*` **не** игнорировать все файлы с расширением

Без правила `!*/` каталоги без расширения `.` в имени не будут перечислены, и ни один из ваших желаемых файлов не будет добавлен за пределы корневой папки.

---

<sub>Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31326382/6104996</sub>

Comment: Замечу, что это не заигнорит файлы, начинающиеся с точки.